# using a user input in a loop and function

Tags: c++, function

My program takes a user input, `int n`, and prints out the first `n` amount of prime numbers. This is working as intended

eg. if user inputs `8` as n. the program will print :

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

My problem is adding the function `isPrime(n)` (which is not allowed to be changed)

here is what i've tried but im just getting the output :

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19  0 is not a prime number,
```

when it should read `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 8` is not a prime number

```
#include "prime.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{


    int n;

    std::cout << "Enter a natural number: ";
    std::cin >> n;
        for (int i = 2; n > 0; ++i)
        {
            bool  Prime = true;
            for (int j = 2; j < i; ++j)
            {
                if (i  % j == 0)
                {
                    Prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Prime)
            {
                --n;
                std::cout << i << " ";

            }



        }

        if (isPrime(n))
        {
            std::cout << n << " is a prime number." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << n << " is not a prime number." << std::endl;
        }

        system("pause");

    }
```

prime.h :

```
#ifndef PRIME_H_RBH300111
#define PRIME_H_RBH300111

bool isPrime(int);

#endif
#pragma once
```

the definition of `isPrime(int)`

prime.cpp :

```
#include <cmath>

#include "prime.h"

bool isPrime(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (n == 2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((n % 2) == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I cannot alter the `.h` file of `prime.cpp`
I just need the `isPrime(n)` function to work on the `main()` function code
the user input n, does not seem to be taking the number `8`. but instead `0`
giving me the output. `0` is not a prime number
rather than : `n (8)` is not a prime number

Comment: Are you sure you understand the instructions? I suspect you should be using `isPrime()` to test each number in the loop, instead of using your own loop that sets `Prime`, not doing `isPrime(n)`.

Comment: @thesitg944 you just deleted a question you had about prime factorization code. I have a link [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-running-time-and-complexity/editorial) that provides explanation as to 4 coding ways of doing it, from un-optimized to extremely optimized. How it works, and mainly why you only need to seek sqrt of n in your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decrementing `n` in the loop. At the time the loop exits, the value of `n` is `0`.

You can solve the problem by:

1. Using another variable to use in the loop.
2. Keeping a copy of the `n` and resetting the value of `n` after the loop exits.

Here's the second method:

```
int copyN = n;
for (int i = 2; n > 0; ++i)
{
   ...
}

n = copyN;

if (isPrime(n))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are decrementing n in the for loop.  The for loop has the condition 'n > 0', so you know n isn't > 0 when the loop finishes.  You could either save the value of n in a different variable (i.e. "int nOrig = n;") and use that for the prime test, or use a different variable in the loop.